# Insert list of values to JTextField with Java2sAutoTextField

Tags: java, awt, jtextfield

I want th auto generate values for the empId (or empName) when inserting values to the jtextfield

I went through the `Java2sAutoTextField` class but I can't add it in to a jframe.

Here's a part of code I extracted from [here](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/32352-adding-list-jtextfield.html#post142686):

```
List possible = new ArrayList();  
possible.add("Austria");  
possible.add("Italy");  
possible.add("Croatia");  
possible.add("Hungary");  
Java2sAutoTextField autoCompleter = new Java2sAutoTextField(possible);
```

i dont know how to put the above coding into the jtextfield

Also I tried out `JSuggestField`, but I can't add it from netbeans palette.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: @OP: welcome to SO. Please take some time to learn how to format code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! i just had to implement the jtextfield as

```
 List possible = new ArrayList();
    possible.add("");
    possible.add("Austria");
    possible.add("Italy");
    possible.add("Croatia");
    possible.add("Hungary");

 jTextField2 = new Java2sAutoTextField(possible);
```